# MySql: Single query to calculate from two columns of different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables

invoice_tbl

```
+---+---------+
|id | Amount  |
+---+---------+
|1  | 5000    |
|2  | 3200    |
|3  | 7400    |
+---+---------+
```

reciept_tbl

```
+---+-------------+-----------+
|id | invoice_id  |paid_amount|
+---+-------------+-----------+
|1  |      1      | 2000      |
|2  |      1      | 3000      |
|3  |      3      | 6400      |
+---+-------------+-----------+
```

In above case i want to findout balance of invoice by single query so that i can short it by balance amount.

I appriciate your help.

Comment: what your exected output?

Comment: In my experience payments rarely align with invoices so neatly. Where does the invoice_id in the receipt_tbl come from?

Comment: invoice_id came from invoice_tbl id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` where you calculate the balance as `sum(i.Amount) - sum(r.paid_amount)` for each id.

```
select i.id, sum(i.Amount) - sum(r.paid_amount) as balance
from invoice_tbl i
    left join reciept_tbl r on i.id = r.invoice_id
group by i.id
```

Do `LEFT JOIN` to include invoices without any payments.